# Integrating Real Time Messaging Protocol with Wicket

Tags: wicket, rtmp

I am designing my web project by Wicket. There I want to add web cam video capturing facility. I have Recorder.swf which records the video and save in rtmp and Player.swf which playback that saved video. Normally both of the swf are working well, if I open them simply by any browser. But If that two swf are added in wicket application then they are not working. But I have tested other swf, like I have played flv by media player swf file in my project. I can not able to understand what is happening! Can rtmp not be integrated with wicket? Thank you.

Comment: @bert I am really very sorry. It is my fault, because I don't know how to accept an answer, today morning I found the way. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: well, its not mine inconvenience, its yours ;) people will just stop answering your questins.  about your question: can you show some code? I personaly have no experience with rtmp, but perhaps others have,

Comment: @bert thanks. I really very sorry that I don't have the actionscript code as it is in my friend's machine and he is out of station. But there is no problem with rtmp and jetty server(wicket).The problem is in my machine running in Fedora. The webcam of that laptop is alright as the single .swf file generated by that actionscript is working properly when it is opened by any web browser like Mozilla Firefox or Chrome, but when it is attached with wicket application it stop working. So I thought it may be rtmp-jetty integration problem. But it is working perfectly in another machine with Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, it has not much to do with Wicket.
Wicket is on server side.
If it works on some machine but does not on other, then it's most probably a problem either in the flash or on the client side (flash player).